# SELECT PARA REDUZIR VÁRIAS ENTRADAS PARECIDAS EM MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Bom dia pessoal, tenho pesquisado e não achei nada muito útil. Eu tenho um banco de dados de inventário das Estações da minha Rede. O agente instalado em cada estação envia os nomes de programas instalados para a tabela *softwares.name*. Quando faço um `select`, vem diversas entradas semelhantes, como:

> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) - 12.0.40660,
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Additional Runtime - 12.0.40660,
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.40660,
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Additional Runtime - 12.0.40660,
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.40660;

Quando o ideal seria ter apenas uma saída

> "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013"

Tem como fazer isso?

Segue o meu `select`:

```
SELECT s.NAME 
FROM hardware as h, softwares as s 
WHERE h.ID = s.HARDWARE_ID
ORDER BY s.NAME
```

Comment: Qual o seu objetivo ao certo? Apenas pegar no texto `Microsoft Visual C++`? Ou podem existir entradas com texto diferente?

Comment: Meu objetivo é fazer com que entradas quase iguais sejam reduzidas a uma única, tipo: `Microsoft Office 2016 `, `Microsoft Office 2016 exchange 12346` saia como `Microsoft Office 2016` somente.

Comment: Não existe um padrão de pesquisa, acho que não vai conseguir fazer isso!

Comment: Na verdade eu imagino que seja algo mais relativo a strings e tratar a saída. Onde quando houver duas saídas `nome123` e `nome231` seria tratado para ser mostrado como `nome`

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar um `substring` com `subselect` para fazer isto:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.NAME FROM
(
SELECT h.HOST, substring(s.NAME,1, 25) AS NAME
FROM hardware as h, 
softwares as s 
WHERE h.ID = s.HARDWARE_ID AND ORDER BY s.NAME
) as x
```

Comment: A função substring me daria solução apenas para os casos em que aparecem `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Minimum Runtime `, mas quando aparece `Microsoft Office 2016 (x64), Microsoft Office 2016 exchange ultimate (x86) ` já não atende. Gostaria de uma solução que me desse um retorno de uma única saída para nomes iguais ou similares.